# Stream().map() result as Collectors.toMap() value

Tags: java, dictionary, generics, java-8, java-stream

I'm having `List<InstanceWrapper>`, for each element I want to do some logic that will result in some `String message`. Then, I want to take create `Map<String, String>`, where key is `InstanceWrapper:ID` and value is `message`;

```
private String handle(InstanceWrapper instance, String status) {
    return "logic result...";
}

private Map<String, String> handleInstances(List<InstanceWrapper> instances, String status) {
    return instances.stream().map(instance -> handle(instance, status))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(InstanceWrapper::getID, msg -> msg));     
}
```

But it wont compile, I'm getting, how do I put `stream().map()` result into `collectors.toMap()` value?

```
The method collect(Collector<? super String,A,R>) in the type Stream<String> is not applicable for the arguments (Collector<InstanceWrapper,capture#5-of ?,Map<String,Object>>)
```

Comment: Does `handle(instance, status)` result in `String message`?

Comment: Yes, I included this method in my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot map before collecting to map, because then you're getting `Stream` of `String`s and loosing information about `InstanceWrapper`. `Stream#toMap` takes two lambdas - one generating keys and second - generating values. It should be like that:

```
instances.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(InstanceWrapper::getID, instance -> handle(instance, status));
```

The first lambda generates keys: `InstanceWrapper::getID`, the second one - associated values: `instance -> handle(instance, status)`.

Answer (score 3):

You map every `InstanceWrapper` to a String but if you want to use the `InstanceWrapper` later to extract its ID you can not do this. Try something like this instead:

```
return instances.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(InstanceWrapper::getID, (InstanceWrapper instanceWrapper) -> this.handle(instanceWrapper, status)));
```

Edit:

To beautify this, you could simulate currying a little bit like this:

```
private Function<InstanceWrapper, String> handle(String status) {
    return (InstanceWrapper instanceWrapper) -> "logic result...";
}

private Map<String, String> handleInstances(List<InstanceWrapper> instances, String status) {
    return instances.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(InstanceWrapper::getID, this.handle(status)));     
}
```